# Add empty line ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table and I would like to have 4 lines per hour.

Right now is :

```
1. 8h00 '1'
2. 8H00 '2'
3. 9H00 '3'
4. 12H00 '4'
5. 12H30 '5'
```

And would like:

```
1. 8H00 '1'
2. 8H00 '2'
3. 8H00 'New'
4. 8H00 'New'

....

21. 12H00 '4'
22. 12H00 'New'
23. 12H00 'New'
24. 12H30 '5'
```

I hope I have been quite specific.
I created a plunker.

http://plnkr.co/edit/BQ7i57ufj5VTmL5e1t52?p=preview

Thank you in advance

Comment: Not really a clear question. In your plunker the data come already premade and have those two lines. Do you mean you want to generate 2 new lines for those data lines each repeat ?

Comment: based on what you have shown here so far, what you are trying to do will be *incredibly difficult* to do with the data the way it is being supplied.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can create a custom padding class, something like this:

```
  .custom-padding {
    padding-top: 10px;

  }
```

And in column, you can use ng-class, like this:

```
ng-class="($index) % 4 === 0 && !$first ? 'custom-padding': ''"
```

Above line will add custom padding class if index%4 is 0.

I have updated your plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZIap01eQH18z6P3iJ7K9?p=preview

Instead of adding ng-class to every column, you can think of adding this in row.